# What temperature should a USB ASIC Miner have while running?

Tags: asic, mining-hardware

What is the maximum temperature a USB miner should be running at? Mine are at about 60°C/150°F.

Comment: What model do you have - there is quite few USB ASIC miners these day ?

Comment: The sapphire 333Mhz/s Bitcoin branded miner.

Comment: 160°C == 320°F.  There is some doubt as to the actual temperature you are reporting.

Answer (score 1):

If this graphic is true, the miner's PCB should run at around 125°F (51°C)

[image]

However, If [reviews](http://www.amazon.com/review/R3FUPZEXR3K3VL/ref=cm_cr_pr_viewpnt#R3FUPZEXR3K3VL) are to be believed, you shouldn't run it at all.